# How to map div id to Spring MVC's controller method?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, spring-mvc, mapping

I don't know if this is possible at all and I didn't find much information so I have to ask.

I know that Spring MVC listens URL paths, but can I somehow do request mappings to my bootstrap's div id's with it?

I want my controller method to listen example "/form#tab2" path, but the problem is that the URL is always "/form" regardless of what tab is selected. Is there any way to go around this?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "form", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String viewForm(){
    return "form";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "form#tabTwo", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String viewFormTabTwo(){
    return "form#tabTwo";
}
```

I know the above doesn't work, but that's what I would want. Form.jsp is something like this:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
<li class="active"><a href="#home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#tabTwo" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">TabTwo</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
<div class="tab-pane active" id="home">Content of home tab</div>
<div class="tab-pane" id="tabTwo">Content of tab2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Listen to do what? Perhaps Ajax should be consider it?